# superscript/subscript in the labels for gnuplot read from data file

Tags: plot, label, gnuplot

```
1 1 A_{3}
2 2 C_{2}
3 3 ^{5}C_{1}
```

I have an input file like this to be plotted. The third column is for the labels on that point (in latex format). How do I get to appear these labels on the plot as they would appear after the latex compilation (as superscript/subscript/Greek alphabet etc.)

Comment: You may need to look at the epslatex terminal and / or enhanced text mode in the gnuplot manual.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax in the sample you give is acceptable to gnuplot's own enhanced text mode as well as to LaTeX.  So it would be sufficient to say

```
set termopt enhanced    # turn on enhanced text mode
plot 'mydat' using 1:2:3 with labels
```

Most gnuplot output modes ("terminals") will accept this.

But gnuplot's enhanced text mode only handles a small subset of LaTeX. If you need more complicated stuff, you'll need to use one of the LaTeX terminals. In this case do *not* turn on enhanced text mode, since you want to pass the whole string through to LaTeX unprocessed.